# Does use a REST API layer over a GRPC Service a efficient thing to do?

Tags: rest, web-services, api, grpc

I was reading about this [GRPC Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) and wondering if using only the REST endpoint generated by it makes a service more reliable and efficient in any way.

If I'm sending JSON over HTTP first, I lose all the RPC/pb lightweight and async capabilities, right?

What is the point for using this lib, aside from the flexibility to choose one or another service layer?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The main purpose of the project is to keep an avenue for the clients that may not be able to use gRPC, but have the ability to connect to an HTTP/JSON server supported without additional manual work.